# Zoom/Pan on custom subclass and serialization

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bd7kc24a/20/

A coworker and I have hit a snag with our attempt to use canvas and we are looking to have a Rect on the canvas to be the actual work area. We are trying to add a grid and/or dot background to that Rect, but we need that section to not scale when zooming occurs. If there is a simple way to do this, we'd love to know about it, but this is where we are currently.

[image: Tiled area]

The example jsfiddle above kinda does what we need it to do. But we are having issues:

1. Persisting that to the database as well as the redux store.
2. Making sure the grid stays the same pixel distance instead of zooming with objects

So I'm trying to create a custom subclass to re-apply that static canvas background when serialization occurs, however once I've added this base class it will not longer do the loadFromJSON call or hit the callback.

Any help would be appreciated! Especially if there is a simple way to do this that we simply missed in the documentation.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bd7kc24a/20/

```
'use strict';
debugger;

fabric.CanvasMap = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {

  type: 'canvasMap', 

  initialize: function(element, options) {
    this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);
    options && this.set('name', options.name);
    options && this.set('imageRef', options.imageRef);
    this.rescaleBackground(10);
  },
  rescaleBackground: function(scale) {
    const padding = 0;
    this.imageRef.scaleToWidth(scale);
    var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
    patternSourceCanvas.add(this.imageRef);
    patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
      width: this.imageRef.getWidth() + padding,
      height: this.imageRef.getHeight() + padding
    });

    let pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
      source: patternSourceCanvas.getElement(),
      repeat: 'repeat'
    });
    this.setPatternFill(pattern);
  },
  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
      name: this.name
    });
  }
});

fabric.CanvasMap.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
  var _enlivenedObjects;
  object.imageRef = squareImg;
  fabric.util.enlivenObjects(object.objects, function (enlivenedObjects) {
    delete object.objects;
    _enlivenedObjects = enlivenedObjects;
  });
  const newCanvasMap = new fabric.CanvasMap(_enlivenedObjects, object);
  return newCanvasMap;
};

let floorPlan = new fabric.Canvas('floorPlan', {
  hoverCursor: 'pointer',
  backgroundColor: '#cccccc'
});

function reloadFromJSON() {
  let jsonMap = floorPlan.toJSON();
  let jsonMapString = JSON.stringify(jsonMap);
  floorPlan.loadFromJSON(jsonMapString, function() {
      floorPlan.renderAll();
  });

}

//let mapBackground = new fabric.Canvas();
function addShape() {
  let coordinates = floorPlan.getVpCenter();
  const circle = new fabric.Circle({
    name: 'some circle',
    radius: 20,
    fill: 'blue',
    left: coordinates.x - 20,
    top: coordinates.y - 20
  });
  floorPlan.add(circle);
}

let defaultScale = 10;
let squareSVG = '<svg width="10" height="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g>  <title>background</title><rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="12" width="12" y="-1" x="-1"/></g><g>  <title>Layer 1</title>  <rect id="svg_1" height="9.87496" width="9.99996" y="0.062519" x="0.031269" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/> </g></svg>'
let squareImg;
fabric.loadSVGFromString(squareSVG, function(objects, options) {
   squareImg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
   const map = new fabric.CanvasMap({
    imageRef: squareImg,
    height: 300, width: 300,
    left: 20, top: 20,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    stroke: 'red',
    selectable: false,
    evented: false, hasBorders: true, hasControls: false
  });

  floorPlan.add(map);
  floorPlan.renderAll();

});

function setBackground(scale) {
    floorPlan._objects[0].rescaleBackground(scale);
}


//logic for binding objects to MAP
floorPlan.observe('object:moving', function(e) {
  let obj = e.target;
  if (obj.getHeight() > map.height || obj.getWidth() > map.width) {
    obj.setScaleY(obj.originalState.scaleY);
    obj.setScaleX(obj.originalState.scaleX);
  }

  obj.setCoords();

  if (obj.top - (obj.cornerSize / 2) < map.top ||
    obj.left - (obj.cornerSize / 2) < map.left) {
    console.log(map.top, map.left);
    obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top - obj.top + (obj.cornerSize / 2) + map.top);
    obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left - obj.left + (obj.cornerSize / 2) + map.left);
  }

  if (obj.top + obj.height + obj.cornerSize > map.height ||
    obj.left + obj.width + obj.cornerSize > map.width) {
    obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, (map.height + map.top) - obj.height + obj.top - obj.top - obj.cornerSize / 2);
    obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, (map.width + map.left) - obj.width + obj.left - obj.left - obj.cornerSize / 2);
  }
});

//zoom
let clicks = 0;
floorPlan.on('mouse:down', function(event) {
  clicks += 1;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (clicks > 1) {
      console.log(event.e.clientX);

      floorPlan.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(event.e.clientX, event.e.clientY), floorPlan.getZoom() + 1);
    }
    clicks = 0;
  }, 300);
});
function zoomIn() {
  floorPlan.setZoom(floorPlan.getZoom() + 0.5); 
  console.log(floorPlan.getZoom(), defaultScale * floorPlan.getZoom());
  setBackground(defaultScale / floorPlan.getZoom());
  floorPlan.renderAll();
}

function zoomOut() {
  floorPlan.setZoom(floorPlan.getZoom() - 0.5); ;
  console.log(floorPlan.getZoom(), defaultScale * floorPlan.getZoom());
  setBackground(defaultScale / floorPlan.getZoom());
  floorPlan.renderAll();
}

function renderAll() {
  floorPlan.renderAll();
}
//pan

function pan(event) {
  event.e.preventDefault();
  let panAmount = {
    x: event.e.deltaX,
    y: event.e.deltaY
  };

  //logic for binding the map to the screen during pan
  /*
   * We need to use the following points and check for negative or overflow values
   * canvas.oCoords.tl - top left
   * canvas.oCoords.bl - bottom left
   * canvas.oCoords.tr - top right
   * canvas.oCoords.br - bottom right
   */

  //pan left
  if (panAmount.x > 0) {
    if (map.oCoords.tr.x < floorPlan.width - 40) {
      panAmount.x = 0;
    }
  }

  //pan right
  if (panAmount.x < 0) {
    if (map.oCoords.tl.x > 40) {
      panAmount.x = 0;
    }
  }

  //pan up
  if (panAmount.y > 0) {
    if (map.oCoords.bl.y < floorPlan.height - 40) {
      panAmount.y = 0;
    }
  }

  //pan down
  if (panAmount.y < 0) {
    if (map.oCoords.tl.y > 40) {
      panAmount.y = 0;
    }
  }

  // assuming the logic above allows the scroll, get the relative scroll values and create a new fabric point and then scroll to it
  const delta = new fabric.Point(-panAmount.x, -panAmount.y);
  floorPlan.relativePan(delta);
}

floorPlan.on('mouse:wheel', pan);
```

Comment: Have you tried using a pattern of squares for the background?